# Format of S3 pre-signed URLs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create an S3 pre-signed URL in my JavaScript code using:

```
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucketName', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is ', url);
```

After executing, my console log shows:

> The URL is https://myBucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/myAudioFile.mp3...

but I think it should be showing:

> The URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketName/myAudioFile.mp3...

Why would it place the S3 bucket name before "s3.amazonaws.com" in the URL?

In the past it was working fine using this method. Has the AWS SDK changed?

Comment: Your bucket is accessible either way.  Is this causing a problem?

Comment: Note that http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cat.png is a virtual-hosted–style URL, while http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/cat.png is a path-style URL. Both are valid.

Comment: Both are valid *only* for buckets in us-east-1.  Path-style must reference the regional endpoint, otherwise, e.g. `https://s3.us-east-3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket` for us-east-2.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the format of signedURL for AWS s3 bucket. When AWS form a signed user for `getObject` or `putObject` this format remain same.

Format for AWS signed url is:

1. `https://`
2. `bucketName` provided. this is `Bucket`
3. `.s3.amazonaws.com/`
4. `fileName` provided. This is `Key`

Since we can't change the format of coding or URL or function provided by AWS, thus more important then format is **Does URL does what you want it to do? Is this URL able to download s3 file and expire after 60 seconds?**

Do follow these [docs over AWS signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html).

Comment: FYI sometimes the region is in there now